# Why don't these ElasticSearch fields appear in "Fields"?

Tags: c#, enums, elasticsearch, kibana, nest

I can't figure this one out. I'm creating a new ElasticSearch index using the ElasticProperty attributes/decorators. Here's how I create the index:

```
        client = ClientFactory(indexName);
        if (!client.IndexExists(indexName).Exists)
        {
            var set = new IndexSettings() { NumberOfShards = 1 };

            var an = new CustomAnalyzer() { Tokenizer = "standard" };
            an.Filter = new List<string>();
            an.Filter.Add("standard");
            an.Filter.Add("lowercase");
            an.Filter.Add("stop");
            an.Filter.Add("asciifolding");
            set.Analysis.Analyzers.Add("nospecialchars", an);

            client.CreateIndex(c => c
                .Index(indexName)
                .InitializeUsing(set)
                .AddMapping<ItemSearchable>(m => m.MapFromAttributes())
            );
        }
```

And all of my fields are being created properly from the attributes specified on the class, except these two. They are C# enumerations, which is maybe part of the problem. I'm trying to save them in the index as numeric fields...

```
    [Required, ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Store = true, NumericType = NumberType.Short, IncludeInAll = false)]
    public Enums.PlatformType PlatformType { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Store = true, NumericType = NumberType.Short, OmitNorms = true, IncludeInAll = false)]
    public Enums.ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
```

When I set up the index and check via Kibana, I don't see PlatformType or ItemType at all in the list of fields in the empty index.

When I insert a record, I can see the values in the source (JSON) as numbers (as expected), but the "Fields" are not there.

So I'm thinking it's either because they're C# enum type, or because I'm trying to store it as a number. But I'm stumped on why Elasticsearch is skipping these fields. Many thanks for any ideas you may have.

UPDATE 1 ... The search still works (even without those fields being shown in the Fields section). I'm thinking it might just be a Kibana problem. In the Table view, it shows my two fields like this...

[image]

and hovering over those triangle exclamation marks says "No cache mapping for this field. Refresh your mapping from the Settings > Indices page". But of course I can't find such a page within Kibana.

So I might be fine behind the scenes and this is a non-issue. Does anyone else have any insight on what might fix this, make it clearer, or whether this is known behaviour and I should just move on? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "at all in the list of fields in the empty index" and "Fields are not there", you mean when nest gives you back the object, aren't you seeing any values in the PlatformType and ItemType properties?.

Comment: When I use Kibana to view the record, it shows everything in the "_source" field, but there's also a "fields" section that I expected to contain each of the fields for which I specified the "Store = true" attribute. Is that not the correct way to think of it?

Comment: I've seen someone indicate online that if I'm not using ElasticSearch as a data store, that there's no need to store _any_ fields, but is that true even if I'm querying and sorting against specific fields? I figured anything that's going to be part of a Filter would have to be a stored field. Right?

Comment: I saw this when I introduced a new data source that had new field names.  I resolved it by regenerating the "Index Pattern" via the "Management" tab of the Kibana UI.